# Macbook Pro mid 2015 + Dell P2721Q + DP - mDP cable not booting after restart in clamshell mode

Tags: display, startup, displayport, thunderbolt-display, restart

I am pretty happy with the combo I have currently but this issue drives me nuts.

I am using **Macbook Pro 15" mid 2015** with **Dell P2721Q 4k monitor** connected with **DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort** cable. I am also using Apple Magic Keyboard and Apple Magic Trackpad which are irrelevant to the issue but still I have to mention them.

The laptop is closed (clamshell mode) and everything works except when I have to restart the laptop.
When I restart it the monitor loses signal. I press keys on the keyboard and tap the trackpad but it never awakes.
*Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced > Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer* is enabled.

If I open the laptop and wake it from its own keyboard it works but I do not want to do that every time as I have 4 cables connected to the laptop (*power, display, USB3-USBC for the monitor hub, sound*) which are tied with velcro and its not the most convenient thing to unplug and plug them back in in order to to wake the laptop.

**EDIT**: I noticed I may have mislead you with the statement above as when I restart the Mac I cannot wake it even if I open it. I have to long press the power at least twice and it goes to the password recovery screen.

I have to note that sometimes when I open the laptop it is in a Password Recovery screen.
I reset the NVRAM and I think this issue disappeared but I try to not restart my laptop often because the whole procedure is annoying so I cannot confirm this Password Recovery issue is trully gone.

Comment: Have you tried [resetting the System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)? And what happens if you're booted into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201262)? Can you restart fine without losing the signal to your monitor?

Comment: As an experiment, can you disable Automatic Graphics Switching (System Preferences -> Energy Saver) and see if this continues?

Comment: I reset the SMC but nothing really changed. When I restart the Mac the monitor loses video signal and never gets it back. I noticed I may have mislead you so I edited my question above.

Comment: I do not have Automatic graphics switching under Battery (I'm using Big Sur)

Comment: I'm assuming you checked the Power Adapter tab on that too, right? What does `pmset -g | grep gpuswitch` show you?

Comment: It returns `gpuswitch 2`